# vSphere Client unable to attach the virtual machine console

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I was using vSphere Client to connect my ESXi 6 server, but can't attach to any virtual machine console via Internet.

vSphere Client has error message:

> Unable to connect to the MKS: Login(username/password) incorrect

[image]

Can telnet the ESXi 443 and 902 port.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, solved this issue by allowing few ports by host firewall (902, 903, 443). Make sure it isn't blocked on both sides.

Also, there are some options here https://communities.vmware.com/thread/238478

Answer (score 0):

As of version 6 web UI is the only fully compatible client for ESXi. Try connect via browser:

```
https://11.22.33.44
```

where 11.22.33.44 is your host IP-address.

Comment: But I can use vSphere Client before, and I need to using VMware Workstation to mount some USB drivers to virtual machine, so I must using the client